# session.save() doesn't work if Cascade type is not All?

Tags: hibernate

```
public class Instructor{
    @OnetoOne(cascade=CascadeType.Persist)
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail")
    public InstructorDetail detail;
}
```

strategy is strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY for both db is mysql
when i create 2 transient entities for both these classes and set InstructorDetail inside Instructor and use session.save(instructor).

I get error "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:", but when i use session.persist(instructor) both entities are saved to db?

what is the difference between save and persist wrt to CascadeType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information in the Java API doc of Hibernate Session:

```
/**
 * Make a transient instance persistent. This operation cascades to associated
 * instances if the association is mapped with {@code cascade="persist"}
 * <p/>
 * The semantics of this method are defined by JSR-220.
 *
 * @param object a transient instance to be made persistent
 */
void persist(Object object);
```

So this method works because you have defined @OnetoOne(cascade=CascadeType.Persist)

```
/**
 * Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or
 * using the current value of the identifier property if the <tt>assigned</tt>
 * generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the
 * association is mapped with {@code cascade="save-update"}
 *
 * @param object a transient instance of a persistent class
 *
 * @return the generated identifier
 */
Serializable save(Object object);
```

So to make it work you must added cascade save-update
BUT: save-update is Hibernate specific and not JPA. So you should not use save.

And better don't use Hibernate Session at all but instead use JPA EntityManager.